# FlatMap And Init in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, flatmap

**Struct**

I tried to recreate the codes in demo given by Chris Edihoff in dotSwift 2016 Demo. Here is the code.

```
struct List {
    let name:String
    let id:Int
}

extension List {
    init?(json: [String:AnyObject]) {
        guard
            let name = json["name"] as? String,
            let id = json["id"] as? Int else
        {
            return nil
        }
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
    }
}

let listData = json["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Everything seems fine till now. But this is where the problem comes.
He did something like this:

```
let list:[List] = listData.flatMap(List.init)
```

The above line is supposed to be returning Array of List Objects. Chris Edihoff seems to be doing it without any problem, but when I do that Xcode warns

**- flatMap produces 'U?', not the expected contextual result type '_?**

Also what is `List.init` here? I have never seen this way of initialisation of object. It should be `List()` or if we are using customer initialization here, it should be `List(json:someObject)` right?

Reference to Chris Edihof Talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewk-XNzXzAA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different reasons why this code does not compile.
First of all, there is no need for you to subscript `json["data"]` - it's going to be flatMap's job to iterate over that data and initialize the lists.

I see that in the original presentation, `listData.flatMap` follows a `if let` block; meaning listData will be unwrapped and not nil.

In your code, instead, you have `let listData = json as? [[String:AnyObject]]`.  Your listData is an optional of type `[[String:AnyObject]]?`.
So, the way to solve this issue is:

```
if let listData = json as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
   let list = listData.flatMap(List.init)
   //do something with list
}
```

Here, listData is of the correct type: `[[String: AnyObject]]`.

Regarding `List.init`, it is simply a way of explicitly applying the initializer to whatever flatMap provides. You can rewrite that function in a more verbose - but probably clearer - way:

```
listData.flatMap {data in List(json: data)}
```